# How to skip delimiter in R when splitting the vectors

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df.

```
df <- data.frame(SNP = c("chr2:178514676:CT:C", "chr2:178514676:CT:CTT", "chr2:178515045:T:<*:DEL>", "chr2:178515048:<*:DEL>:T"))
```

I want to split `df$SNP` by `:`, but if there are <*:DEL> I want to keep it as a whole element.

The result df should have additional 4 columns:

```
SNP                    new_CHR new_POS    REF   ALT
chr2:178514676:CT:C    chr2   178514676   CT    C
chr2:178514676:CT:CTT    chr2   178514676   CT    CTT
chr2:178515045:T:<*:DEL>     chr2   178515045   T    <*:DEL>"
chr2:178515048:<*:DEL>:T    chr2   178515048   <*:DEL>    T
```

I was creating the four columns like this, but won't give the right result because `<*:DEL>` also gets split.

`df$REF <- sapply(strsplit(df$SNP, split=":"), "[", 3)`

Answer (score 3):

One option is to include a `gsub` step in your pipeline. Whereas you had:

```
df %>% separate(SNP, into = c("new_CHR", "new_POS", "REF", "ALT"), sep = ":", extra = "merge")
```

You could change this to:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(SNP = gsub(SNP, pattern='<*:DEL>', replacement = '<*DEL>',fixed=T),.keep='unused') %>% 
  separate(SNP, into = c("new_CHR", "new_POS","REF","ALT"), sep=":", extra='merge')
```

This just replaces occurrences of "<*:DEL>" with "<*DEL>" so it is not split on the delimiter. If you like you could include another `gsub` after the `separate` function that puts the colon back in.

Comment: simple enough. I was looking into writing the exception inside the regex, but this stepwise approach is pretty straightforward

Answer (score -1):

We could remove extra arguments within **mutate()** function. So, A more simplified code could be like below.

```
# We can use '<\\*:DEL>'instead of '<*DEL>' as we are not interested in substitution.


df %>% 
  mutate(SNP = gsub('<\\*:DEL>', '<*DEL>', SNP)) %>%
  separate(SNP, into = c("new_CHR", "new_POS","REF","ALT"), sep = ":", extra = "merge")

  new_CHR   new_POS    REF    ALT
1    chr2 178514676     CT      C
2    chr2 178514676     CT    CTT
3    chr2 178515045      T <*DEL>
4    chr2 178515048 <*DEL>      T
```